# how to check if the url matchs the identifier?

Tags: java, regex, string, match

```
String identifier = "(/news/|/finace/)&from=ucweb"
String url = "/news/abroad/zhuanti?nid=122334&from=ucweb&foo=sthelse"

public boolean ifMatch(String url, String identifier) {

}
```

find if the url match the identifier.

The identifier is not a regex pattern, I'm thinking like that:

split the identifier with (, ) , | , & 4 charactors，then check if the url contains "/news/", "/finance/", "from=ucweb"， then math the result.

but I don't know how to implement it, can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (url.matches("^.*from=ucweb.*$")
            && ( url.matches("^.*/news/.*$") 
            ||   url.matches("^.*/finance/.*$"))) {
        System.out.println("match found");

    }
```

Comment: In the identifier , "|" means "or", "&" means "and", so how to chech match?

Comment: the "&" means "and", not the & in common url means.

Comment: Thank you, but if the identifier is different from this, but also like (...)|(...&...(...|...)), how to?